# Custom Framework for Writing a Test that Reads a CSV File into a HashMap

Tags: java, eclipse, csv, maven, testng

I am trying to complete a lab where the teacher has asked us to write a test that can read a csv file into a hashmap. He gave us two files one called 'ConfigurationProvider.java' and another called basses.csv to use to write a data driven TestNG case.

ConfigurationProvider.java looks like this

```
package framework;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ConfigurationProvider {

    public HashMap<String, String> getPropertiesFromResourceFile(String fileName) throws Exception {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try {
            inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);

            if(inputStream == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException(fileName + " was not found in the Resources folder.");
            }

            properties.load(inputStream);
        }
        finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }

        HashMap<String, String> propertyValuesByKey = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
            String value = properties.getProperty(key);
            propertyValuesByKey.put(key, value);
        }

        return propertyValuesByKey;
    }
}
```

and basses.csv looks like this

```
Make,Model,StringCount
Warwick,Corvette,5
Warwick,Thumb,5
Warwick,Streamer,5
Fender,Precision,4
Fender,Jazz,4
Yamaha,BB500,5
```

So far I have written the test as follows

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import framework.ConfigurationProvider;

public class BassesProvider {

    @Test(dataProvider = "bassProvider")
    public void canPrintMap(String make, String model) {
        System.out.println(make + ":" + model);
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "bassProvider")
    public Object[][] getData() throws IOException {
        
        String FILE_PATH = 
                "C:\\Users\\name\\git\\practice\\automation\\src\\test\\resources\\basses.csv";
        
        ConfigurationProvider basses = new ConfigurationProvider();
        try {
            basses.getPropertiesFromResourceFile(FILE_PATH);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        Object[][] data = new Object[2][7];
        data[0][0] = basses;
        
        return data;
        
    }
}
```

I am getting the error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.InputStream.close()" because "inputStream" is null`, etc... and I'm not sure what changes to make or how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure what changes to make or how to proceed further.

First you need to work out why the code is throwing an NPE.

- Look carefully at the stacktrace.
- Work out where the NPE is thrown.
- Work out where the `null` comes from.

Hint 1: carefully read the javadoc for the method that is setting the variable that contains the `null`.

Now my understanding is that your actual task is to write unit tests.  And (without giving the game away) the reasons you are getting an NPE are a combination of a bug in the code you are testing and a flaw in the way that you have (ummm) set up the test environment.

Hint 2: The `ConfigurationProvider` code that you are testing is NOT designed to load data from a file in the file system.  See Hint 1.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not even sure if I'm supposed to ConfigurationProvider as part of the test or if I should be creating my own DataProvider. There weren't very clear instructions. I just looked at it, saw the HashMap and thought it might be useful. But I might be wrong. I did also create my own simple DataProvider but I couldn't figure out how to return it as an Object[][] and thus use it in the test because I am unsure how to set up the environment. This is only my second time with TestNG and I'm unsure of how these things really work.

Comment: Seriously ... if you don't what you are supposed to be doing in this exercise, the **first** thing you should do it so find out.   Ask your teacher to clarify the instructions.